# PHP MySql Compare 2 Columns in Different Tables, Perform a Calculation & Output Result

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 tables with **exactly the same structure** called table_new & table_old respectively. The table structure is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_new` (
  `Club_Number` int(11) default NULL,
  `Club_Name` varchar(60) character set utf8 default NULL,
  `Active_Members` int(11) default NULL,
  `Goals_Met` int(11) default NULL,
  `Last_Updated` date NOT NULL,
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here's what I want to do:

**Step 1.** 
Compare table_new against table_old where table_new.Active_Members is greater than table_old.Active_Members **OR** table_new.Goals_Met is greater than table_old.Goals_Met WHERE table_new.Club_Number equals table_old.Club_Number

**Step 2.**
If something positive is found (the results are greater than zero), calculate the difference between:

1. table_new.Active_Members and table_old.Active_Members & echo the results
2. table_new.Goals_Met and table_old.Goals_Met & echo the results

How do I achieve this using PHP & MySQL? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you shall use LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN to perform such a query

Comment: What does the '6' in INT(6) do? (This may be a trick question)

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you required output

```
SELECT table_new.Active_Members, table_old.Active_Members, table_new.Goals_Met, table_old.Goals_Met FROM table_new 
INNER JOIN table_old ON table_new.id = table_old.id
WHERE (table_new.Active_Members > table_old.Active_Members OR table_new.Goals_Met > table_old.Goals_Met) 
AND table_new.Club_Number = table_old.Club_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful to you

```
select convert(t_n.Active_Members - t_o.Active_Members, SIGNED) as 'Active Members',
convert(t_n.Goals_Met - t_o.Goals_Met, SIGNED) as 'Goals Met'
from table_new as t_n inner join 
table_old as t_o 
on t_n.Club_Number = t_o.Club_Number
where t_n.Active_Members > t_o.Active_Members OR 
t_n.Goals_Met > t_o.Goals_Met;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP script display difference.

```
$result=$db->query('SELECT tabn.`Active_Members` as active_new, tabo.`Active_Members` as active_old, tabn.`Goals_Met` as goals_new, tabo.`Goals_Met` as goals_old FROM `table_new` as tabn LEFT JOIN `table_old` as tabo ON tabn.`Club_Number`=tabo.`Club_Number` WHERE (tabn.`Active_Members` > tabo.`Active_Members`) OR (tabn.`Goals_Met` > tabo.`Goals_Met`)');

if(count($result) > 0)
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

echo 'Difference in Active_Members is: '.$row['active_new'] - $row['active_old']."\n";
echo 'Difference in Goals_Met is: '.$row['goals_new'] - $row['goals_old']."\n";

}
```